# Shell script to create new file on right click for macOS

Tags: macos, shell

I would like to add a context menu item in MacOS Mojave which gives the option to create a new file in the finder on a right click (the way you would in windows). I would also like to be able to specify the file type (text, word, html, css, javascript, etc)

I have followed a tutorial online in order to create the context menu item with automator but I am not familiar with writing shell scripts.

is it just as simple as:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    touch "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement this following the instructions here: [How to get Create New Text File from context menu](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8285995)

The only drawback as it stands is that you need to select a folder in finder to get the context menu. I would like to be able to click in the current I am in and get the menu but I can live with this. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

[This tool](https://samiyuru.com/project/macOS-finder-right-click-menu) provides the "Create a file here" option out of the box. With this tool you can easily create your own options as well by writing simple shell scripts. The tool is free and the page has a link to the source if you want to check the source. The source has a shell script that creates a file in a directory that is given as an argument to the script. The script avoids file name conflicts when creating new files.